# Replace text with user friendly text in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am populating a table using jquery from an Ajax payload. In one of the table column am displaying text which is user-unfriendly. This is the text directly fetched from the Ajax object.

Before displaying the text, I am planning to make it user friendly.
This is what I have tried so far:-

The jquery ajax success method is -

```
function userfriendly(nametype){
                                                //var ufname = filetype;
                                                console.log(filetype);
                                               var obj = {"sdf":"DAm     
  good","qw":"Fine","er":"Expected","as":"Dumb Ass","zx":"Zoom","sd":"Secure data"};
                                                            console.log(filetype);
                                               var ufname = obj+'.filetype';
                                                    console.log(ufname);
                                               return ufname;
                                            };

                                             userfriendly('sdf');


  $('#myTable').append("<tr><td>"+item.cTime+"</td>   
 <td>"+item.cTime+"</td><td>"+item.bName+"</td><td>"+item.status+"</td></tr>");
```

The function userfriendly should accept the 'nametype' as the unfreindly name & return a friendly name from the object using key value pairs.

For eg:-
It accepts nametype as 'er' & returns 'Expected' from the object.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure exactly what you're trying to do - but perhaps this will lead you the right way:

```
function userfriendly(nametype) {
    var obj = {"sdf":"DAm good","qw":"Fine","er":"Expected","as":"Dumb Ass","zx":"Zoom","sd":"Secure data"};

    return obj[nametype];
}
```

All that does is take the parameter nametype and uses it as the index to the object and returns the associated value.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! If this worked for you, you can mark this answer as the "Accepted answer".